# Calling TLS1.2 from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, tls1.2, winhttprequest

I cannot call a RESTfull API from Excel VBA because the API using TLS1.2.
There is, apparently, no way in VBA to set the option to use TLS1.2. I tried setting WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS option but it is being ignored.

Does anyone know about a possible solution? Preferably the one that does not involve changing registry.

Comment: Did you check the MSDN article [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as a default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in)?  It does require registry additions, though, but there is an Easy Fix available to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and found out that the problem was that in Windows 7 the WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS flag does not include TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 protocols.

So if you have Win7 you can check here for a potential solution:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi